# How to Work with NavigationService.Navigate in Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How To declare "?msg=" in WP8.1...?

i tried this code is working in WP8

In WP8

```
 private void passParam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + textBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

coming to WP8.1 used Frame.Navigate

In WP8.1

```
 private void passParam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage.xaml) + textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Then how to declare "?msg=" in WP8.1....?

Comment: you can have only one parameter

Comment: yes how to declare that parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `Frame.Navigate` you will see, the second parameter is a navigation parameter you can pass. Take a look at http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-navigating-from-page-to-page-how-it-differs-from-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Then how to add "?msg=" it is not given in the refered link

Comment: Check part "Passing Parameters"

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1, Page Navigation method is:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);
```

or

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

In your code, you can set param to be yours like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), textBox1.Text);
```

You can find the documentation [for this here MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Comment: Then how to pass parameters in that

Answer (score 0):

As people already wrote, what you need is:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), textBox1.Text);
```

The second paramater can be actually any object.
Then, to get the paremeter in SecondPage you can do this (in your case):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    String your_text = e.Parameter as String; 
}
```